# Degree of a restriction of a continuous map?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have a map $f:D^2 \rightarrow S^2$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for $x \in S^1$. Does this mean that $\deg(f|_{S^1})=0$? if so, why? We defined this degree on $S^1$ as $f(\exp(t))=\exp(F(t))$ then $\deg(f)=F(1)-F(0)$. I also know that $\pi_1(D^2)=0$ and $\pi_1(S^1) =\mathbb{Z}$, if this is of any help.

Comment: As noted by Lee Mosher, the notion of degree is meaningless in the context of maps $S^1\to S^2$. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every map from $D^2$ to $S^1$ is null-homotopic because $D^2$ deformation retracts onto a point, and so in particular so is the restriction of such a map to a subspace of $D^2$. A null-homotopic map from the circle to itself has zero-degree as the constant map has zero degree and degree is a homotopy invariant.

It is in fact also the case that a map $f\colon S^1\to X$ is null-homotopic if and only if $f$ can be extended to a map $\tilde{f}\colon D^2\to X$ such that $\tilde{f}|_{S^1}=f$.

Comment: but how does this follow from my definition? I mean I see that the fundamental group of $D^2$ is zero, but the degree of $f$ is defined differently.

Comment: A null-homotopic map from the circle to itself has zero-degree as the constant map has zero degree, and degree is a homotopy invariant.

Comment: why is this map 'null-homotopic'? is this obvious?

Comment: A map $f\colon X\to Y$ is null-homotopic if there exists a homotopy $H\colon X\times [0,1]\to Y$ between the map $f$ and a constant map $c\colon X\to Y$. If you haven't seen these terms before then it's possible you're meant to answer this question using more elementary techniques - was this assigned in an introductory algebraic topology course?

Comment: yes, but we have not really covered this yet. So I need to show that we have such a homotopy between $f$ and a constant map? Well, the map $c:X\rightarrow Y$ would imply that I shrink in $Y$, but I want to shrink in $X=D$, cause $D$ is null-homotopic?

Comment: Suppose $H_t\colon [0,1]\times D^2\to D^2$ is a homotopy from $\mbox{Id}_{D^2}\colon D^2\to D^2$ to the constant map $c_{\ast}\colon D^2\to D^2$ where $\ast$ is a point in $D^2$, then $f\circ H_t$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $c_{f(\ast)}$.

Comment: $f |_{S^1}$ is a map from $S^1$ to $S^2$. Degree is undefined for maps between manifolds of different dimensions, so the expression  $deg(f |_{S^1})$ is meaningless.

Comment: @LeeMosher I must have missed that $f$ was a map to $S^2$, I thought it said $S^1$. I wonder what the question was meant to be now, as it probably then isn't how I originally interpreted it either as the condition that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ isn't used.